# How can I convert an IntVector to an Int in z3py

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py

I am using z3py and I have an `IntVector` of size 3. I need to parse each digit in the `IntVector` as one whole number. Meaning, if I have an `IntVector` which has constraints like this:

```
myIntVector = IntVector('iv', 3)
s = Solver()
s.add(iv[0] == 5)
s.add(iv[1] == 2)
s.add(iv[2] == 6)
….
```

I need to be able to operate on the number 526 as an `Int` sort in z3 because I need to both add constraints that apply to each individual member of the `IntVector` (digit) AND constraints which apply to the whole number, in this case 526. I cannot do something like:

`s.add(iv[0] / iv == 55)`

because those are 2 separate types. `iv[0]` is an `Int` while `iv` is an `IntVector`

Comment: What's wrong with `100*iv[0] + 10*iv[1] + iv[2]`?

Comment: That thought crossed my mind but I wasn't sure if there was a more idiomatic conversion. I suppose I could write an extension function in python which handles this too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses the concept of IntVector as separate digits and as numbers formed by these digits.
It solves the traditional riddle to replace each of the letters of "SEND + MORE = MONEY" to a different digit.

```
from z3 import *

# trying to find different digits for each letter for SEND+MORE=MONEY
letters = 'SENDMOREMONEY'
iv = IntVector('iv', len(letters))
send = Int('send')
more = Int('more')
money = Int('money')

s = Solver()

# all letters to be replaced by digits 0..9
s.add([And(i >= 0, i <= 9) for i in iv])

# the first digit of a number can not be 0
s.add(And(iv[0] > 0, iv[4] > 0, iv[8] > 0))

# distinct letters need distinct digits
s.add(Distinct([i for k, i in enumerate(iv) if letters[k] not in letters[:k]]))

# "send" is the number formed by the first 4 digits, "more" the 4 next, "money" the last
s.add(send == Sum([10**(3-k)*i for k,i in enumerate(iv[:4])]))
s.add(more == Sum([10**(3-k)*i for k,i in enumerate(iv[4:8])]))
s.add(money == Sum([10**(4-k)*i for k,i in enumerate(iv[8:])]))

# the numbers for "send" and "more" sum together to "money"
s.add(send + more == money)

if s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()

    # list each digit of iv
    print([m[i].as_long() for i in iv])

    # show the sum as "send" + "more" = "money"
    print("{} + {} = {}".format(m[send].as_long(), m[more].as_long(), m[money].as_long()))
```

Comment: Was this answer helpful?